# Integrate Pidgin into the Me Menu, or help fix Empathy?

Tags: empathy, pidgin, irc

Is there any way to integrate pidgin into the Me Menu, or any other chat applet?

My main problem is that everyone I know uses AIM, which Empathy jokingly supports.

Or is there a way to fix Empathy to make it show which AIM users are mobile?

Comment: This should be two questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Pidgin is already integrated in MeMenu. Simply go to Tools -> Preferences then set "Never" to "Show system" tray icon in the Interface tab.

Comment: I remember seeing it there as well.